# Could impedance mismatch explain my distorted signal?

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, impedance-matching

I have a custom PCB which scales and offsets an analogue signal, using an instrumentation op-amp (INA114). When I use a scope to look at the output, it looks distorted (see images below). When I use a T-junction at the input to look at both the input and output signals on the scope, the output is no longer distorted. What is the cause of this distortion?

Here is a diagram of the configuration:

[image: Diagram]

The DAC spec says that its "load impedance" is \$50\Omega\$. The scope, I assume, has an impedance of \$1\text{M}\Omega\$. The custom PCB connects directly to the op-amp, which has an input impedance of \$1\text{M}\Omega\$. Schematic can be seen at [https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH1tL.jpg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH1tL.jpg).

And here are the good (both input and output connected to scope) and bad (only output connected to scope) waveforms:

[image: Good waveform]

[image: Bad waveform]

Comment: Reflections with a 10kHz signal?    Not likely.    Check your scope ground.   Are you clipping it near the DAC or on the 'scale and offset PCB'?

Comment: Lack of good grounds between sig gen , DAC, INA , all Power supplies and 10:1 probe ground of scope.

Comment: The DAC output circuit could be being destabilised by the high op-amp impedance. Try shunting the line to 0v with a resistor in the 47-100 ohm range, or higher if that is all you've got.

Comment: Wind the timebase out (more ms per division). You'll see your desired output is amplitude modulated by something else ... almost certainly at 50Hz or 60Hz according to where you are. Then look at the Photon's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the schematic of your gain and scaling circuit that you hid in an external image:

[image]

You don't show any connection between the ground of the DAC circuit and the ground of the amplifier circuit. This could lead to the inputs of the amplifier being well outside the power supply rails.

When you connect both the DAC and amplifier circuits to the scope at the same time, you also connect their grounds together, and eliminate this problem.

You can make the system work without the scope present by connecting the shield of the coaxial connector on the amplifier input to the amplifier circuit's ground. Possibly you could do this with a resistive/capacitive connection rather than a direct connection, depending on how far apart these two boards will be in your system, what kind of shield currents you expect, etc.